# Trouble connecting to SSL enabled mongo cluster from Spark Application

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a SSL enabled mongo cluster from a spark application. I'm trying to use self signed cert and getting the following error.

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server CLUSTER_NAME
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:525)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:413)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:106)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching CLUSTER_NAME found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
```

My read config uri looks something like this:

```
    val uri: String = "mongodb://" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8") + ":" + URLEncoder.encode(Password, "UTF-8") + "@" + cluster + ":27017/" + database + "." + collection + "?authSource=" + (if (authenticationDatabase != "") authenticationDatabase else "admin") + (if (replicaset == null) "" else "&replicaSet=" + replicaset) + "&ssl=true"
```

I want to use self signed cert something like :

```
 class TrustAllX509TrustManager extends X509TrustManager {
    override def getAcceptedIssuers = new Array[X509Certificate](0)

    override def checkClientTrusted(certs: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {
    }

    override def checkServerTrusted(certs: Array[X509Certificate], authType: String): Unit = {
    }
  }
```

The version of the env's I'm using:

Spark: 2.2.0
Mongo: 3.4

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: OP please insert read config uri example, or remove the reference to it in your details.

Answer (score 0):

This is same as making any other SSL connection. Import your cert in keystore and refer to that key store using below code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keystoreFilefullpath")

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password")
```

Once these params are set then Kafka SSL should work. If you are publishing from Spark then keystore file must be uploaded to driver/executor using --files option